# Can the server side JS function access another OrientDB directly?

Tags: orientdb

In our SaaS system(one database per tenant), tenants need to communicate with each other. To support this, we hope that javascript functions created in OrientDB 1 can connect and query another OrientDB 2.

I tried like that.
[image]
I can not fix the bug. Maybe, I misused the JS API. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that from functions with:

```
var extdb = new com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.script.OScriptDocumentDatabaseWrapper("remote:192.168.1.182/db2");
extdb.open("admin","admin");
```

Comment: Hi @Lvca. I tried your code and it works. Tks!    So, I need to query the extdb, where is the API?

Comment: Try executing this before any query: `extdb.activateOnCurrentThread();`

Comment: When adding "extdb.activateOnCurrentThread()", exception comes: "TypeError: extdb.activateOnCurrentThread is not a function in <eval> at line number 41"